# Recyclerview Duplicate Values with LiveData onBackPressed in Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, viewmodel, observers

I have a recyclerview with load more, and I can't store the values in the database. So when I load the data, everything works perfectly. The problem occurs when I navigate to another fragment, and click onBackPressed, the onChanged of the observer is being called again and it is giving me the last values called from the API. Then as you can see in the code below, they are automatically being added to the list and published in UI

```
 productsViewModel.productsObject.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { result ->
        if (result.status != Status.LOADING) {
            (activity as MainActivity?)!!.dismissProgressDialog(getView())
            if (result.status == Status.SUCCESS && result.data != null) {
                val productsResult = parseObject(result.data.asJsonObject)
                if (!productsResult.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                    products.addAll(productsResult)
                    productAdapter.submitList(products)
                    progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
                    numberSearch.text = products.size.toString() + "/" + total + " " + resources.getString(R.string.items_found)
                } else if (result.status == Status.ERROR) {
                    if (result.message.isNullOrBlank())
                        Utils.showSnackBar(requireContext(), view, getString(R.string.something_wrong_try_again), true)
                    else
                        Utils.showSnackBar(requireContext(), view, result.message, true)
                }
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: The onChanged will be called with previous values in LiveData when the fragemnt is restored. One thing you can do is in the getter of LiveData you can clear it and return. So that each time you call observe you get a fresh LiveData.

Comment: how do I clear the liveData?

Comment: In your live data getter, before you return the live data, reinitialise it with `livedata = MutableLiveData()` so that you will receive a fresh live data.

Comment: good idea let me try it. Yesterday at night I switched from transformations so that I would use MutableLiveData

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you are not observing your `result` correctly.

For example, if the value of `result` is `Status.LOADING` what happens? After you enter that block, maybe there are other cases that you are not handling. We don't know because there is no other `when` or `else if` block.

Another way more "clean" would be:

```
productsViewModel.productsObject.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { result ->
    when(result.status) {
        Status.LOADING -> manageLoading()
        Status.SUCCESS -> manageSuccess()
        Status.ERROR -> manageError()
        else -> manageBaseCase()
    }
}
```

Thus, it is not all embedded in a unique `if` block making the management more understandable.

In your Fragment you should manually send an event to "reset" the actual state of the LiveData so that you will be sure that there won't be duplicate items.

Your Fragment may look something like this:

```
class ProductsFragment : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.product_fragment, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        observe()
        productsViewModel.send(Event.Load)
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, this is not the case because the status when the fragment is popped back from the stack is actually success.

Comment: Where is your ViewModel initialized? In `MainActivity` or in `Fragment`?

Comment: fragment in the ovViewCreated

Comment: After you `observe()` your state in `onViewCreated()` you should send an event to reset the actual state.

`productsViewModel.send(Event.Load)`

Comment: Good idea, trying it now

Comment: worked and I think it is the best answer better than clearing the live data. Please update your answer so that I could mark it as correct

Comment: Done. Glad that it worked, let me know if the answer is clear enough otherwise I'll try to improve it more.

Comment: @MirianaItani will you share your code here it'll be great help. Thanks in advance